When I'm cross-compiling for a different architecture (Linux amd64 targeting Linux aarch64), glibc version issues crop up
I'm just getting started building an application in C++, and I want to cross-compile it for aarch64, which is the platform it's going to run on.  The target runs Ubuntu 18.04, and when my build laptop was running Ubuntu 18.04, the test worked fine - however, I generally run Ubuntu 22.04 on this laptop, and when moving the build there (everything else is the same!), it links the resulting binary against the wrong version of glibc.
I guess I don't understand why the OS of the build host should matter here; I specified a rootfs directory where the target is installed (see my CMakeLists.txt, below) - so why would it take anything from the build host?  Certainly the actual version of glibc on the target root is correct...
Anyway, this is the CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(cross_test)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/riz/testing/jetson_top_r32.7.2/Linux_for_Tegra/rootfs)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})


...which, as I said, generates a working-on-aarch64 binary when run on an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, but when run on a Ubuntu 22.04 one, the resulting binary gives problems:
linux:~$ /tmp/cross_test 
/tmp/cross_test: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /tmp/cross_test)

What do I need to do to be able to target a different Ubuntu version as well as a different arch? To be clear, the directory in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH is the actual rootfs of the target machine.

[1/2] The target machine needs access to the shared library versions that were used at compile time.  This creates a problem on your Ubuntu 22.04 host machine, because it means you'll need older and newer versions of some dpkgs installed on the same box.  One solution is to have a VM or a chrooted environment that has the correct libraries installed that won't conflict with your host system.

[2/2] Another way is to build those shared libraries from source, and make sure that when you compile your program, you link against those libraries (that you built) and not the ones sitting on your host system.  This means that you'll need to track down the exact version of source code used to generate the packages that reside on your Ubuntu 18.04 target, which sometimes is not easy.
